# Formula for comparing multiple cells with random values in excel and return conditional output

Tags: excel

I need a formula to perform below operation in MS excel. Here is the scenario:

[image]

My case is I have to compare 4 cells in a single row. 3 of the cell values are similar and 1 will be unique always. They can be in random sequence but there will be an unique value and 3 duplicate values while comparing 4 cells. As you can see in the result column, I need the output which is the unique value. Please help me to write the formula.

Comment: show us what you have tried first.

Answer (score 1):

If your cells contain only numbers, here's an approach using `SUMIF` and `MODE.SINGL`

```
=SUMIF(A2:D2,"<>"&MODE.SNGL(A2:D2))
```

[image]

---

For text or numbers, you can use an array formula - enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=INDEX(A2:D2,MATCH(MIN(COUNTIF(A2:D2,A2:D2)),COUNTIF(A2:D2,A2:D2),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What if the cell values are characters instead of numbers?